# Lots of mysql processes log error too many open files

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, logging

I'm having problems with a CentOS server thats running slowly, htop shows about 40 lines of this which I think is causing the problem:

```
27218 mysql      20   0 17.7G 7449M  5088 S  0.0 46.8  0:00.24 /usr/libexec/mysqld /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql/ --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --open-files-limit=102400 --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Server has 16 GB of RAM and the 17.7G is in red. The open files limit was previously 65535 so I increased this to 102400 but it still shows the same error with the higher number.

Can anyone please point me in the direction of how I can begin to debug this? I've checked mysqld.log and it had nothing relating to this, it seems the error is that it cannot write to the log file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess at 2 issues:

1. Your system is set to limit your mysqld user daemon process to the default 1024 open files. Set this to a much larger value and then restart mysqld:

   ```
   echo "mysql soft nofile 65536" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
   echo "mysql hard nofile 102400" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
   ```
2. Your innodb_buffer_pool_size is too large for your wired memory:

Edit your my.cnf and check the value for that. Perhaps try 50-60% of wired memory. Other settings, such as the per thread buffer sizes will affect that, particularly with large numbers of connections/sessions.

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G
```

Less likely - check your system-wide limits on open files with:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

You can set that with the following value in /etc/sysctl.conf, e.g.:

```
fs.file-max = 204800
```

Then load that sysctl change with:

```
sysctl -p
```

Answer (score 0):

The stats to look out for is the chucky 46.8% mem which indiated high physical memory usage.  The 17.7G includes swap and so might not be indicative.  Increasing open files limit to 102400 might not help if system limits are already 65535.

I'm seeing similar/recurring lines on my test servers (centOS7 + WHM/cPanel build on a VPS).  Test apps are running ok with 10-20% mem usage but performance was otherwise brisk.